# I am having a parsing issue while converting JSon data from php file

Tags: android, json

The odd part here is it worked... then I attempted something which didn't work, so went back to my old code, which is currently not working. The error takes place during the parsing of data.

here is my code.

```
    //@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    InputStream isr = null;
    String result = "";
    TextView resultView;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            result = new httprRequest().execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getData();
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);


    }

/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
*/
    public void getData(){
        String s = "";

    //parse json data
        try {

               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

               for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
                   JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   s = s + 
                           "Name : "+json.getString("first_name")+"\n"+

                           "Mobile Using : "+json.getString("mobile_phone")+"\n\n";
               }

               resultView.setText(s);

           } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
           }


    }

private class httprRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params){
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("private");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Server encontered an error.");
                }
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_entity", "Error in http connection: "+e.toString());
                }

            //conversion happening here..
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_buf", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

        return result;

        }
    }
}
```

here is what my php file outputs.

```
[{"first_name":"CHRIS","mobile_phone":"+278285187"},{"first_name":"IAN","mobile_phone":"+64 (27) 582 58"},{"first_name":"ANDRIES","mobile_phone":"+278257922"}]
```

Here is my php code

```
connect();

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT first_name, mobile_phone FROM `admin_contacts`");

$output = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $output[]=$r;

}
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

My JSOn is valid. it is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException..... if that helps.

Thanks Andrew... can't believe I didn't see that -.- ... haha u saved me thx

Comment: Definitely not PHP.  Please re-tag this with the appropriate technologies.

Comment: What appears to be missing from the JSON string you posted are the enclosing `[]` square brackets, to make it a proper array of objects.  If you generated that in PHP, post the _php code_ that generated it, not whatever you're using to read it.  `json_encode()` handles JSON encoding correctly in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't valid json, it should have `[]` around it to mark it as an array

EDIT:

Looks like the actual problem is here

```
    getData();
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
```

the getData function uses resultView before it gets populated.  Swap those lines and that should fix it